# Hibernate 5.0.1 and Java 8; Provider org.hibernate.type.Java8DateTimeTypeContributor not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am learning hibernate. I downloaded the hibernate-release 5.0.1 Final and copied all the jars in the required and java8 folders into my project. I am using java8 jdk in my system.

I am trying to execute a very basic program:

```
  public class HibernateTest {      
    public static void main(String[] args){

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("First User");


        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

The hibernate configuration file is also very basic:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration>                
      <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Training</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="org.vicky.dto.UserDetails"/>
      </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The result is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor: Provider org.hibernate.type.Java8DateTimeTypeContributor not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:365)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.vicky.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:19)
```

Please help me out. I searched in that package for this missing class file. But it is not there. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What all jar file you added in class path?

Comment: Hi Subodh, I have added all the jar files that are in hibernate-release 5.0.1 Final.zip file. I have also added hibernate-java8-5.0.1.Final.jar file to the project.

Comment: Add java 8 in build path/configure build path and also make sure your java installed jre default is 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Remove java8 jar file from build path libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the hibernate-java8 jar in your class path. You can find it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8/5.0.1.Final).

Comment: Hi danizmax, I have already added hibernate-java8-5.0.1.Final.jar file to the project. I am now able to find the org.hibernate.type.Java8DateTimeTypeContributor in this jar file. But I still get this exception. I am unable to understand why this class is not getting detected by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed just now. I have installed multiple eclipse IDEs in my system. Found out that the one I am using with this project is using JDK 1.7. I have changed it to JDK 1.8 and everything got smooth now (Windows->preferences->java->installed JREs->Add and point to JDK 1.8 directory).

But can someone explain how eclipse works here?
I have installed Java 8 RE in my system. May be that's why this particular eclipse is expecting Java 8 related classes but without detecting them even though they are added to the project, because it's "installed JREs" setting is pointing to JDK 1.7 . No clue what exactly is happening here with eclipse.

Thank you for your answers subodh and danizmax. Nice evening!

Comment: You have written "Hibernate 5.0.1 and Java 8" in the title, so we assumed your eclipse project was set to Java 8. My answer was correct, though you had another miss configuration with java 7. You can either accept, my answer or at least thank us by up voting our contributions. This is how the site works.

Comment: My intention was never to upset you. I upvoted your answer but may be because of my reputation it wouldn't be visible to the public at this moment. I said thanks to both of you in my answer above. Please accept my apologies if something upset you without my knowledge. You have asked me to add a jar file that I added already to my project. The java8 folder of the hibernate-release 5.0.1 Final.zip file contains that jar file which I said I added in my question. I just added my answer because that was the one that actually fixed my issue and would help others too.

Comment: It's not problem ;P Jut making sure people up vote. Anyways that's a good question, I would bet you included some other hibernate jar that requires java 8 specific features.

Comment: Thanks :). Yes some jar must have some dependency on this java8 specific class. And eclipse was unable to detect the class even though it was added to the project because the "installed JRE" was jdk 1.7 . I just added the jars in the "required" and "java8" folders of the hibernate-release 5.0.1 Final.zip file that I downloaded from the hibernate website. And the postgreSQL jdbc driver. That's it. I will look into it more tomorrow. Good night!